# How to get roles email address in AppMaker

Tags: google-app-maker

How to get the email address from user roles in AppMaker? I understand that `app.user.role` return a boolean whether the email address was assigned to that role or not. But how do we get the role email address then?

Comment: What's the use case you are trying to achieve? `app.user.role` means it will give role for the logged in user. So you can have logged in user's email via `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()`

Comment: I want to send email to specific roles. My plan is to get the email address and pass it to email var on `MailApp.sendemail(email, subject, body)`

Comment: Ohh. I doubt that is possible currently in Appmaker. There is no method/API which allow us to add/remove/fetch Roles/Users in that role.

Comment: do you mean `that is not possible` ?

Comment: Yes directly there are no APIs, you can achieve this as a way out. Maintain a page  in appmaker which will have all these roles/email mapping. Use that at run time.

Answer (score 0):

[Server API](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/appmaker/scripting/api/server#App) has app.getRoleMemebers() which is what you want:

```
var role = app.roles.Admins;
var members = app.getRoleMembers(role);
```